# Inline insering and editing for radgrid when databinded from serverside codebehind

Tags: gridview, datagridview, telerik, radgrid, inline-editing

In my application i am creating a new grid where i am trying to implement inline inserting and editing for radgrid where data is being binded from serverside code behind , I am trying to adopt the logic implemented in the following article
 http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/alleditablecolumns/defaultcs.aspx
The problem i am facing is in this article its shown for data being from clientside ,please  can i get any other article or sample working project where inline inline inserting and editing for radgrid is being implemented.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo link that you sent along does show the *server-side* automatic CRUD operations with inline editing, not client-side. If you look on the DefaultCS.aspx.cs view you see that all of the CRUD operations are being subscribed to in the code-behind.

Perhaps you are looking for the manual approach as opposed to the automatic approach taken above. [This demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/entityframeworkcrud/defaultcs.aspx) shows off the functionality pretty perfectly, although it doesn't show the in-line edit form.  To display this is easy, as all you have to do is set the **EditMode** property to **InPlace**.